# Regression model for highly correlated financial market variables - regression of difference or regression of values is better?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, linear-model

I work in bond trading. My statistical background is just a few statistics models in university.

A lot of people in my industry use regression analysis (simple linear) to look for dislocations in the marketplace. One common regression I see is regressing the value of say, the spread between two bonds’ yields (2 year and 7 year bonds, the spread between these being a widely traded instrument itself) and say the 10 year bond yield (seen as a benchmark for the bond market and to which all of the 2 year bond yield, 7y bond yield and the 2y/7y bond yield spread are correlated)*. Many regress the level of the 2y/7y bond yield spread against the level of the 10y yield. I’m wondering is there a good argument one would get better results regressing the change in the yield spread vs the change in 10y yield instead, and why?

*all bonds on the same yield curve are correlated generally, and the 2 year/7 year yield spread would tend to tighten as the 10 year yield leads the bond market lower in yield, for the likely many non finance folks out there.

My other question - some regress the 2y/7y spread against the 7y yield ITSELF. Does this not introduce errors in the model given the dependent variable is a linear combination of the independent variable and another?

I’m not asking for someone to spoon feed this to me - if someone  could point me in right direction on some material on this that would be great.

Let’s hear it!